# Can you identify this grub?

Tags: insects

Past couple of years I've been getting skunks digging in the yard. Not a lot but I've had to deal with sprayed pets which is no fun.

I applied Milky Spore past 2 falls but I was doing a little digging and ran across this guy. Any idea what type of grub it might be? I'm thinking it might not be a japanese beetle grub since the milky spore has had no effect on it.

[image: Grub pic 1]

[image: Grub pic 2]

Answer (score 2):

Chafer grub if its not Japanese beetle, but I'm afraid I think it IS Japanese beetle because of the fine hairs - chafer grubs don't have those.

Comment: THanks Bamboo. I just found this page on grubs. https://www.maine.gov/dacf/php/gotpests/bugs/documents/Ohio-State-grub-ID.pdf Looks like I didn't get a good shot of the area that's used to identify them. If I see any more I'll try to take a better shot.

Comment: followed your link, useful, if you don't mind inspecting a creature's rear end at close quarter!

Comment: sometime's a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do :)